# How to verify correctness of a Fenchel conjugate derivation

Tags: numerical-methods, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Suppose I derived Fenchel conjugate of a function.
My goal is to check if my solution is right. Suppose the steps are not available any more and only the final solution is present.

Is there any verification procedure (or a certificate) by which I can make sure that the solution is right or wrong?
Any numerical or analytical procedure is useful.

Or perhaps any tools available for computing Fenchel conjugate of a non differentiable  function?

Comment: One necessary (but not sufficient) condition is to check that $f^*(0) = min_x f(x)$. Another condition to check is to take the convex conjugate again to get $f^{**}$, and try to check if it is the convex-ified version of the original function..

Comment: Additionally, even though your function is not differentiable, you could check the correctness of your conjugate at points where it is differentiable, which is almost everywhere for convex functions.

Comment: For checking biconjugate, I need to make sure it is convex and a lower bound, right? Anything more?

Comment: That is necessary but it's more - the epigraph of the biconjugate is the convex hull of the epigraph of the original function. In particular if the original function is convex and closed then it is equal to the biconjugate. Imagine taking your original function and wrapping it in gift paper like a present. Then the wrapped shape is the biconjugate.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you are given $f$, and have a candidate function $g$ that *might* be equal to $f^*$ (the the fenchel conjugate of $f$), but you're not sure. You can try checking numerically that:
$$f(x) + g(y) \ge \langle x,y\rangle$$
for various values of $x,y$. Any counterexample to the inequality is certificate that $g \ne f^*$. To prove that $g=f^*$, you need to show the inequality is satisfied for all $x,y$, and that for each $y$ there is an $x$ such that the inequality is tight.